# Using reflection to instantiate classes

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to search a specific namespace and return instances of all classes that implement the specified interface and have the specified base class.

Here is the code

```
private List<T> GetInstancesWithInterface<T, T2>(string @namespace)
{
    var tList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                         .GetTypes()
                         .Where(t => t.Namespace == @namespace)
                         .Where(t => t.BaseType == (typeof (T)) && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T2)))
                         .Select(t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this))
                         .ToList();
    return tList;
}
```

And here is the calling code

```
var examples = GetInstancesWithInterface<DrawableGameComponent, IResettable>("GamePhysics.Physics");

foreach (var example in examples)
{
    Debug.Assert(example is IResettable);
    var r = example as IResettable;
    _examples.Add(r);
    Components.Add(example);
    if (Components.Count == 0) continue;
    example.Enabled = false;
    example.Visible = false;
}
```

The problem I am having is the Assert fails because I get back a list of `DrawableGameComponent` which cannot be treated as `IResettable` so the code `var r = example as IResettable` always returns null.

**Additional info**

I should have also mentioned that `DrawableGameComponent` does not implement the `IResettable` interface. My three example classes that I'm trying to fetch all have `DrawableGameComponent` as the base class and they also implement `IResettable`.

**Additional thoughts**

I was thinking that perhaps I should create a new abstract class called `Example` which implements `DrawableGameComponent` and `IResettable` and then my concrete example classes can just implement the `Example` base class. I suppose this *might* be better design but I am also interested to know if I can get it working as it is.

Comment: "because I get back a list of DrawableGameComponent which cannot be treated as IResettable" - I very much doubt that's the problem. The `is` operator should deal with such a situation just fine. Have you stepped through it with a debugger and looked at each object returned?

Comment: Yes, I've stepped through and r is always null. I should have also mentioned that `DrawableGameComponent` does not implement the IResettable interface. My three example classes that I'm trying to fetch all have DrawableGameComponent as the base class and they also implement IResettable. I'll update the question with this extra info too.

Comment: Have you tried `(typeof (T)).IsAssignableFrom(t.BaseType)` (and vice versa) rather than `t.BaseType == (typeof (T))`? If you're looking for `T`'s child classes, then `==` most likely won't work.

Comment: @valverij Thanks for the response but I get the same result using `IsAssignableFrom`

Comment: What about changing the `Select` to `Select(t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t, this))`. The way it's currently set up will create instances of `T` whenever you find a child class, rather than creating instances of the child classes.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much. It now creates instances of the real class so I can successfully cast them into `IResettable`. Please post that as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Posting as requested in comments. Thanks for waiting)

Take a look at the `Select` portion of the LINQ query:

```
.Select(t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this))
```

Passing `typeof(T)` into `Activator.CreateInstance` will create a new object of type `T`. Since you are actually looking to create objects out of your found types, you would want to change this to:

```
.Select(t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t, this))
```

This will ensure that the Activator creates instances of the types found in the previous `Where`.

As Lee also mentioned, using something like `IsSubclassOf` or `IsAssignableFrom` in your `Where` expression is preferable to a straight up `==` when searching for subclasses. From my experience, they work about the same, except `IsAssignableFrom` will also work with interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the wrong type to `Activator.CreateInstance`, you should change it to:

```
.Select(t => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t, this))
```

you might also want to use [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) in your `Where` clause instead of looking at the base class directly.

Comment: Thanks Lee. @valverij already answered in his comment so I'll wait to see if he posts an answer I can accept.

Comment: Thanks for the added info about `IsSubclassOf`, I can see how this would be better.